# Numpy scale down array representing image

Tags: python, image, numpy, scaling

I have an image stored in a numpy array ~180x130 pixels.

I want to scale it so that the image is NxN but keep it so that aspect ratio is kept. This will mean black space around the dimension that is smaller.

Is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html). A small example:

```
 a = np.ones((4,2))
 np.pad(a, ((0,0), (1,1)), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0))

 array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]])
```

In your case, I guess you want the second argument to be `((0,0), (25,25))` to pad with zeros in the 25 columns either side of your image array. (Of course you should pad with whatever constant values represent "blank space" to you for your image format).

Comment: I padded the dimension that was smaller with some ifs to make it square and then used misc.imresize. Thanks